# ZIP compress all files (*.txt) in a directory and subdirectory c#

Tags: c#, file, compression, zip

I need your help, I am new to C#.

I have a program that compress a folder with all its files and folders, but I would like to just compress a specific kind of file.

I use this code to compress:

```
if (!File.Exists(name_of_zip_folder))
{
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folder, name_of_zip_folder);
}
```

I would like to do the following:

```
public void Zipfunction(string folder, List<string> files_to_compress){
    //compress these kind of files, keeping the structur of the main folder
}
```

For example:

```
Zipfunction(main_folder, new List<string> { "*.xlsx", "*.html"});
```

How could I compress only specific file types?

Answer (score 1):

This is a code snippet from [Jan Welker](http://dotnet-snippets.com/user/jan-welker/0) [(Originally posted here)](http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/using-sharp-zip-lib-to-compress-files/586) that shows how to compress individual files using [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx)

```
private static void WriteZipFile(List<string> filesToZip, string path, int compression)
{

if (compression < 0 || compression > 9)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid compression rate.");

if (!Directory.Exists(new FileInfo(path).Directory.ToString()))
    throw new ArgumentException("The Path does not exist.");

foreach (string c in filesToZip)
    if (!File.Exists(c))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The File{0}does not exist!", c));


Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
ZipOutputStream stream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(path));
stream.SetLevel(compression);

for (int i = 0; i < filesToZip.Count; i++)
{
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(filesToZip[i]));
    entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filesToZip[i]))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        entry.Size = fs.Length;
        fs.Close();
        crc32.Reset();
        crc32.Update(buffer);
        entry.Crc = crc32.Value;
        stream.PutNextEntry(entry);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
stream.Finish();
stream.Close();
```

}

Now combinding this with something like this that gets files from a specific folder and you should have what you were asking for if I did not missunderstand your request?

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Get txt files
List<string> filesToZip = new List<string>();
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
    filesToZip.add(file.Name);
}
```

Hope it helps 
//KH.

Answer (score 1):

To create zip archives from a wildcard filtered source you use [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and manually create a [ZipArchiveEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137429%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for any file that meets the specified search criteria. The last page lists a sample that illustrates this. To search in a directory with a wildcard pattern you can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx).